# Enabling smooth activity transition when changing between Day/Night mode

Tags: java, android, android-night-mode

I use the following code to switch between Day/night mode in my application:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(isChecked
     ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
     : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

     if (isChecked) {
        editor.putBoolean("isDarkModeEnabled", true);
        editor.apply();
     } else {
        editor.putBoolean("isDarkModeEnabled", false);
        editor.apply();
}
```

When I switch modes, the activity blinks and is recreated. How can I have a smoother transition when switching modes (e.g. fade-in/fade-out between switching)? Can I use overridePendingTransition(), or is there another convenient way?

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi nope, I didn't manage. My app blinks when changing between day/night modes.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: @George Any luck with this?

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit Unfortunately no, it still "blinks" while transitioning between light/dark modes.

Comment: Sad, it works fine in tutorials i watched. lol

Comment: The smooth transition is available in Android L, I think it was removed on newer version.

Answer (score -4):

Insert below codes in your styles

```
<style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

and add this line your theme.
    @style/WindowAnimationTransition

Then you have smoother transition.

Or visit https://medium.com/@rohitksingh/start-your-activity-with-slide-animation-ae63017e4b7d for specific activity

Comment: Well, the issue with this is that it overrides all activity transitions for my app. I'd like to leave the default android version transition for that, and just get rid of the "blinking" when switching between DayNight modes.

Comment: You can try overridePendingTransition(enterAnim,exitAnim) after startActivity
and you can check this article for more
https://medium.com/@rohitksingh/start-your-activity-with-slide-animation-ae63017e4b7d